# Jest mock function calls is not counted

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I want to mock a function post from an object. I did it like this:

```js
jest.mock('../../apis.js', () => {
  return () => {
    return {
      post: jest.fn(() => {
        console.log('POST was called !');
        return Promise.resolve();
      }),
    };
  };
});
```

Then, I make my require:

```js
const apis = require('../../apis');
```

Finally I call my service which will call the `post()` function from `apis` module:

```js
client.doPost()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('count: ', apis().post.mock.calls.length);
    expect((apis().post)).toBeCalled();
  });
```

The `doPost()` function calls the mocked `post()` one ('POST was called !' message is printed) but `count is equal to 0` and expect fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs to be checked but I guess that the variable you access in your `apis().post.mock.calls.length` call is not the same as the one that is used in your `client.doPost()` call.

Indeed, when you call `apis()`, your mock returns a new object at each call.

What you want to do is storing the stub in a dedicated variable and access it in your `then()` test:

```
const postStub = jest.fn(() => {
  console.log('POST was called !');
  return Promise.resolve();
});

jest.mock('../../apis.js', () => {
  return () => {
    return {
      post: postStub,
    };
  };
});
```

Then to use it (should be on the same file of course):

```
client.doPost()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('count: ', postStub.mock.calls.length);
    expect((apis().post)).toBeCalled();
  });
```

Comment: `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: postStub

Answer (score 0):

Workaround

```
global.iPost=0;

jest.mock('../../apis.js', () => {
  return () => {
    return {
      post: jest.fn(() => {
        console.log('POST was called !');
        global.iPost++;
        return Promise.resolve();
      }),
    };
  };
});

expect(global.iPost).toEqual(1)
```